# Checking if certain info is already in database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I know the title sounds like something that has already been posted But I promise I have taken the time to do my research and have found nothing for my problem.

I am not new to mysql I know how to grab info from the database and check it, but the way I want to check it is my issue. I have a subscription system that I have been building everything is working fine even the checking -- at first. what Is happening is I have made 2 test accounts when one of the test accounts subscribes to the other is is perfectly fine my script says that that user is subscribed to the user, and my database results support it. But when the other user subscribes back, the script that checks does not return correctly. I'm not sure if it is the way that my script is checking or if it's the fault in my logic and the way my database is setup.

I have a table called 'subs' with 5 columns
id, user, subed, accepted, date

the way I am checking if the user has subscribed to the other is by finding the row where user is the same as the user who is subscribing, and subscription is the same as the user who is being subscribed to. at the moment the 'accepted' row is not being checked because that is an option in the settings which has not been created yet.

I'm sure it will turn out to be an obvious answer that will make me feel and look really stupid, or something I have overlooked, thanks for taking the time to help, here is the function that seems to be messing up.

```
function subcheck($user, $sub){

    $user = strtolower($user);
    $sub = strtolower($sub);

    //connect to the database
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=postreme', '****', '****');
    $dbh->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");

    $check = $dbh->prepare("SELECT user FROM subs WHERE subed=:subed AND user=:user");
    $check->bindParam(':subed', $sub);
    $check->bindParam(':user', $user);
    $check->execute();
    $checks = $check->fetchColumn();
    $checks = strtolower($checks);

    if(!empty($checks)){
      return true;
    } else { 
      return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: "at the moment the 'accepted' row is not being checked because that is an option in the settings which has not been created yet". I don't understand this?

Comment: `SELECT user` should be `SELECT subed` as you want to check the sub right. And it should be `!empty($checks) && $checks==$user`

Comment: @AndrewGibson sorry, the accepted is only going to be checked if the user wants the subscription to be accepted before the actual subscription occurs it will still create the row but the subscription will not be counted until the person who is being subscribed to accepts it or is deleted when it is denied, the "option in the settings which has not been created yet" part is because I will have settings page to turn the option on and off, but im still early in the development and have not gotten that far yet, I only mentioned it do you wouldn't get confused from an extra column not being checked

Answer (score 1):

Query for return 1 if record exist and 0 if not exist:

```
select case when (select 1 FROM subs WHERE subed=:subed AND user=:user) is null then 0 else 1 end;
```